# php isset array is always false

Tags: php, arrays, isset

Hi this is my code to do some basic navigation. No matter what i do, when i pass parameter "stranky", it always prints "first else". I have also tried array_key_exist function, also with no luck. Any ideas?

```
if(isset($_GET["stranka"])) {
$page = $_GET["stranka"];
$povoleneStranky = array("vsichni", "vecery", "pridej_vecer", "uprav_index");

if (isset($povoleneStranky[$page])) {
    $stranka = "$page.php";
    include $stranka;
    echo $page;

} else {
    include ('vsichni.php');
    echo "first else <br>";

}
else {
    include ('vsichni.php');
echo "second else";
}
```

Comment: `"stranky"` !== `"stranka"`

Comment: You can't have 2x else.

Comment: Show us the code of your HTML `form`, if any.

Comment: You are passing `stranky` but retrieving `stranka`? Whats the value you are passing to `$_GET["stranka"]` ? Also, after ` echo "first else <br>";` add a `}`

Comment: Unbalanced parantheses

Comment: sorry typo im passing stranka...i have no form only anchors like this <a href="profile.php?stranka=vsichni">Some text</a>

Comment: @Houdasek, you are referencing to the value and not to the key.

Comment: `if(condition){ statement }elseif( condition ) { statement} else { statement }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the code to :

```
$povoleneStranky = array("vsichni", "vecery", "pridej_vecer", "uprav_index");

if (isset($_GET["stranka"]) && in_array($_GET["stranka"], $povoleneStranky)) {
    $stranka = $_GET["stranka"] . ".php";
    include $stranka;
    echo $_GET["stranka"];
} else {
    include ('vsichni.php');
}
```

Check if this is working.

**SOLUTION 2** - More Optimized One:

```
$povoleneStranky = array("vsichni", "vecery", "pridej_vecer", "uprav_index");
$stranka = 'vsichni.php';

if (isset($_GET["stranka"]) && in_array($_GET["stranka"], $povoleneStranky)) {
    $stranka = $_GET["stranka"] . ".php";
}

include $stranka;
```

Comment: Yes this is working. So isset is not suitable for checking for a value in an array?

Comment: `isset` checks for the offset in an array. We must use `in_array` for checking the array values.

Answer (score 0):

The array has no "string" indexes/keys, only numeric and the items inside it are all string values, so using `in_array()` is the better way to check.

```
if (isset($povoleneStranky[$page])) {
```

should be

```
if (in_array($page, $povoleneStranky)) {
```

...unless `$_GET["stranka"]` has a numeric value, in which case my answer is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you are useing array `$povoleneStranky = array("vsichni", "vecery", "pridej_vecer", "uprav_index");`
this array is somethig like this in php `array([0]=vsichni[1]=>vecery[2]=>pridej_vecer[3]=>uprav_index);`

so you can so it always return run else because it never finds `$povoleneStranky[$page]`  you can try  `isset($povoleneStranky[0])`

Answer (score 0):

First of all close parantheses

```
if(isset($_GET["stranka"])) {
$page = $_GET["stranka"];
$povoleneStranky = array("vsichni", "vecery", "pridej_vecer", "uprav_index");

   if (isset($povoleneStranky[$page])) {
       $stranka = "$page.php";
       include $stranka;
       echo $page;

   } else {
       include ('vsichni.php');
       echo "first else <br>";

   }
}
else {
    include ('vsichni.php');
echo "second else";
}
```

Because right now like someone said you can not have 2 else.
Also var

```
$povolenestranky
```

is not in your case mulidimensional array and you trying to get

```
$povolenestranky[$page]
```

wich not exist if page is a string.